# Metastore in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

Is there a recommended solution for storing metadata of table/file schemas while using Azure Synapse Analytics Spark Pools. data will be written in either parquet/delta table format.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below reference it has a detailed explanation about storing metadata of table using Azure Synapse Spark Pool and configure Spark to use the external Hive Metastore.

**Reference:**

[External Hive Metastore for Synapse Spark Pool by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-external-metastore)